# Set of infinitely differentiable functions compactly supported in a domain of $\mathbb{R}^n$ not dense in $L^\infty$

Tags: functional-analysis, self-learning, lp-spaces

How does one show that the set of infinitely differentiable functions compactly supported in a domain $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is not dense in $L^\infty(\Omega)$? Thanks!

Comment: The uniform limit of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: Look at $\lVert \varphi - 1\rVert_{L^\infty}$ for $\varphi$ with compact support.

Comment: @T.Bongers, Daniel Fischer So I've managed to do this much: Consider the Heaviside function $\theta(x)$. Any continuous $g$ with $||\theta-g||_\infty<\dfrac{1}{3}$ must have $g(x)<\theta(x)+\dfrac{1}{3}=\dfrac{1}{3}$ for all $x<0$. Continuity thus gives $g(0)\leq\dfrac{1}{3}$, which is in contradiction to $g(0)>f(0)-\dfrac{1}{3}=\dfrac{2}{3}$. Where do I go after this?

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Yes, that's a good idea. You can make a generalization of this idea for $\mathbb{R^n}$ and $\Omega$: Without loss of generality, $0 \in \Omega$. Then define $\theta(x) = 1$ if all the coordinates of $x$ are positive.

Comment: @T.Bongers Ok. Then, where do I go?

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar Given a continuous $g$, the above shows that there is a neighborhood of zero on which $|g(x) - \theta(x)|$ is not small; thus $\theta$ is not the $L^{\infty}$ limit of continuous functions.

Comment: @T.Bongers So this shows that the set of infinitely differentiable functions compactly supported in a domain $Ω⊂\mathbb{R}^n$ is not dense in $L^∞(Ω)$, right?